# How can I generating a table with code below

Tags: arrays

A long loop

```
for(int a = 1,b = 10, c = 11, d = 20, e = 21, f = 30, a <= 10, a++, b--, c++, d--, e++, f--)
    System.out.println(a + " " + b + "   " + c + "  " + d + "  " + e + " " + f);
```

Comment: Can you show what you expect this to produce, what it has to do with arrays, and what language this is?

Comment: @ScottHunter This is Java almost certainly.  But it's totally unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as below and you will have your expected table.

```
  for(int a=1,b=10, c=11, d=20, e=21,f=30; a<=10;a++,b--,c++,d--,e++,f--)
        System.out.println(a+ " " +b+ "   " +c+ "  "+d+ "  "+e+ " "+f);
  }
```

That is after the **declarations** you should have a **;** not a **,** . And then, again after the **condition** also you should have a **;** not a **,**